# Fetching data using C# POST in JS

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I need to get the resulting string of function resultado2() of the following link:

http://barion.inapi.cl/BuscaBiblio/proceso.js

As a first step, I wrote the following code:

```
            string url = "http://barion.inapi.cl/BuscaBiblio/inicio.php";
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);

            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            string buscar = "solicitud=" + 750 + "&registro=&descripcion=&solicitante=&d=1&m=1&y=" + 2003 + "&d2=31&m2=12&y2=" + 2003; // +"&nocache=0.1821407969109714";
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(buscar);
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Until here, all is well. 'responseString' gives me 'ok##1', which indicates there is one result so far.

However, I'm stuck where function resultado2() returns the string which returns the HTML code including the required table.
I tried with this code:

```
            url = "http://barion.inapi.cl/BuscaBiblio/listado.php";

            uri = new Uri(url);
            request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as System.Net.HttpWebRequest;
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.Method = "POST";
            postData = "st=0&total=1";

            data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            response = request.GetResponse();
            responseString = new StreamReade
```

But it gives me a 500 error.
However, upon trying with the debug mode of Chrome, I clearly can inspect the value of 'r'.

```
function resultado2() {
    if(peticion_http.readyState == READY_STATE_COMPLETE) {
        if(peticion_http.status == 200) {
            mm = document.getElementById("resultado");
            var r = peticion_http.responseText;
            mm.innerHTML = r;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, are you trying submit the data from your client to the server side?  If so, your approach is somewhat peculiar.  You can simply do the following:

```
function Calculate() {
     var order = new Array();
     var convertedOrder;

     // Do whatever you need or want to validate.

     // BuildOrder a function to build our object cleanly.
     order.push(BuildOrder(product, quantity, price, shipping, other, location, tax)); 

     // Convert object to Json
     convertedOrder = JSON.stringify(order);

    // The array and converting data into JSON would be wrapped in a loop.

   $.ajax({
         url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Services/Order.aspx") %>',
         data: { Order: convertedOrder },
         type: 'POST',

         success: function (order) {
              var result = JSON.parse(order);
              console.log(result[0].Total); // Returned data
         }
}
```

The above is quite primitive, but you at least get the idea.  Then on the server for C#, you do an `object` that will store all the data your passing:

```
// Data to be read and parsed.
public class Returnable
{
    public int Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }        
    public decimal Shipping { get; set; }
    public decimal Other { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public decimal Tax { get; set; }
}

// Data to Send Back:
public class SendInformation
{
     public string Tax { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your code behind for your `.aspx` you do this in `Page_Load`:

```
 JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 List<Returnable> deserialize = serializer.Deserialize<List<Returnable>>(order);
 foreach(Returnable returnable in deserialize)
 {
     // Iterate through all of your passed data.
 }

 List<SendInformation> responseObject = new List<SendInformation>();
 responseObject.Add(new SendInformation() { Total = "value", Tax = "value" });
 string response = serializer.Serialize(responseObject);
 Response.Write(response);
 Response.End();
```

That will push data from Client to Server, then Server back to Client so you can use data.  Even call it in new functions and other areas.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Upon new review of the js query, I found I need to implement '.onreadystatechange' event in my C# code, at the time the request is made asynchronously.